# unknown error connecting to bokeh-server windows 7

Tags: python-3.x, bokeh

I have bokeh installed by pip3.
I am trying to connect to my bokeh-server. The server itself runs on its own console window and starts up fine (I can access the GUI), and the server config is printed out in the cosole: python version 3.4.2, bokeh version:0.9.3, listening: 127.0.0.1:5006, backend: memory, multiuser on, rest off.

Then i open a second console window and try to create a plot in the server by writing in ipython:

```
from bokeh.plotting import hplot, figure, show, output_server, Session
from numpy import arange, sin, cos

session = Session(root_url='http://127.0.0.1:5006/', load_from_config=False)
session.login('user', 'password')
```

It then hangs at this last line, finally giving the error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
RuntimeError                         Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-2-1154f347a037> in <module>()
----> 1 session.login('user', 'password')

C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\bokeh\session.py in login(self, username, password)
    236         })
    237         if result.status_code != 200:
--> 238             raise RuntimeError("Unknown Error")
    239         result = get_json(result)
    240         if result['status']:

RuntimeError: Unknown Error
```

Does anyone maybe know what is going on?

Thanks!

Comment: This problem seems to be windows specific, works just fine on my macbook.